# What is a word for something that is done in substitute for something else to prevent worse effects?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to think of a word for something that is done as a substitute to something else that is considered to be worse (especially if that thing is still not completely permissible in the eyes of some). As an example, someone may say, "Well, I have to still do marijuana to get the edge off. Hey, at least it's better than me drinking alcohol, right?"

Comment: Maybe you are looking for 'harm reduction' or 'mitigation.' Are you specifically referring to the use of a less harmful substance?

Comment: You may perhaps invert some idioms like "moving from bad to worse" or "jumping out of the frying pan into the fire" to "moving from worse to bad" or  "jumping out of fire into the frying pan".

Comment: _Kludge_ /kludʒ/ is a term used in engineering and computer science for an inelegant work-around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Anodyne** (n.)

> *fig.* Anything that soothes wounded or excited feelings, or that lessens the sense of a misfortune. OED

> Anything that relieves distress or pain:
> *The music was an anodyne to
> his grief.* [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/anodyne)

> Something that soothes, calms, or comforts [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anodyne)

---

> The sun disappeared on April 17th and **work became the anodyne to
> winter**.
> [James Hayes; *The Conquest of the South Pole: Antarcti  Exploration, 1906-1931*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=The%20sun%20disappeared%20on%20April%2017th%20and%20work%20became%20the%20anodyne%20to%20winter.) (1932)

> In Hamper's account, **drinking** created worker solidarity and was an
> act of resistance, **an anodyne to drudgery**, and a labor enhancer. It played a role in the social reproduction of the working class and wreaked havoc with his family life, first as the child of a drinking father and in his own adult life, and with his health.
> [D. Bradburd and W. Jankowiak; "Drugs, Desire, and European Economic Expansion" in *Drugs, Labor and Colonial
> Expansion*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Drugs_Labor_and_Colonial_Expansion/4v16EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=drinking%20as%20An%20anodyne%20for&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

> **Tobacco** has been called **the anodyne of poverty**, and the opium of
> the western world. To Parr, whose nerves were extremely irritable, and sensibility immoderate, perhaps it was a necessary **anodyne**.
> [William Chatto; *A Paper:—Of Tobacco; Treating of the Rise, Progress, Pleasures, and Advantages of Smoking. With Anecdotes of Distinguished Smokers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_paper_of_tobacco_treating_of_smoking_b/jnUEAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=smoking%20as%20An%20anodyne%20for&pg=PA91&printsec=frontcover) (1839)

> The same is true with reference to **analgesics**, though there frequently
> arise conditions in which they become **the lesser of two evils**, at
> least in a humanitarian sense. It should always be remembered that to
> give an **anodyne** is not to treat disease.
> [Merck's Archives, Vol.
> II](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Merck_s_Archives_of_the_Materia_Medica_a/Qi8TAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=anodyne%20lesser%20of%20two%20evils&pg=PA365&printsec=frontcover) (1900)

Comment: You may also propose "antidote".

Comment: I don’t see how this answers the question. Marijuana and alcohol are both anodynes for “taking the edge off.” What is a word for substituting one for the other, in the sense of choosing the lesser of two evils?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I interpret this as asking for "a word for something done...," not the *act of doing something* else. The OP's example is marijuana for alcohol. I think the question is What is the marijuana functioning as in this case? Alcohol is doing more than taking the edge off if it leads to oblivion.

Comment: *Substitute* is the operative word there — “something that is done in substitute.”

Comment: @Graffito It's customary here to put just one suggestion in an answer, so someone else (e.g. you) can post their answer. Also, it becomes impossible to tell which answer an upvote is being awarded to if there are more than one. I shouldn't get credit for an answer that someone else comes up with. Finally, an OP can change their accepted answer if they think a better one has come along.

Answer (score 3):

It’s a phrase, not a word, but I would say, “The lesser of two evils.”

Comment: What is done may in some cases be “the lesser of two evils” but the phrase does not itself define what is done so does not answer the question. You might reasonably have discussed it in the context of “preventative”, “palliative”, “lash-up”, “precaution” and similar concepts, but it is not a front-runner. Good answers on this site usually show some research or synthesis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).